# Intercepting and stopping a celery beat task before publishing to message bus

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I am using signals to intercept celery beat tasks before publishing.  This works fine.  But, in addition I want to execute some logic and, based on the result, possibly cancel the task.

I cannot find a way to cancel the task from the event handler, aside from raising an exception and that seems very inelegant.

The background is that I am implementing distributed task processing using cache locks and I am performing CAS operations on the lock before publishing.

Is there any way to implement this using current celery/celerybeat functionality?

Thanks